# Azure table service global replication

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

Azure table service account provides option to replicate data onto paired secondary location in case of RA-GRS. Is there any option to replicate the data globally in multiple regions as read copies. I am looking for this option as we can have multiple instance of applications in each region which can use the read copies in local region for reads.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Storage accounts can indeed be replicated with different modes (LRS, ZRS, GRS and RA-GRS). GRS and RA-GRS are basically same in that they replicate to a secondary data center, RA-GRS just makes the secondary readable.

The secondary data center is already set, and you cannot have a third one.

What I would instead suggest is to use Azure CDN to get the files closer to the local regions. That does require that the files remain relatively static for maximum benefits though.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to use several (more than 2) replica if using a special client library. Called "Replicated Table Library for Microsoft Azure Storage"

see: https://github.com/Azure/rtable